# Reconnect to source and continue from last emitted value

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I'm trying to figure out how to implement reconnect to observable after a transient failure, to continue from a last emitted value.

Assume I have the following method:

```
interface MyQuery {
  fromId: number;
  toId: number;
}

interface MyItem {
  id: number;
  val: string;
}

function observeUnstable(query: MyQuery): Observable<MyItem>;
```

The method `observableUnstable` lets to subscribe to a stream which emits values and may emit the following error in case of intermittent connection failure:

```
class DisconnectedError extends Error;
```

I want to compose a new observable which would wrap the original observable above and have transparent resubscribe from the position at which the previous subscription has failed.

The data types are going to be opaque, so I would want to make the reconnection logic generic, probably as an operator which would accept a high order selector function:

```
let startQuery = { fromId: 1, toId: 10 };

let reconnectable = observeUnstable(startQuery)
       .lift(new ReconnectOperator<MyItem>((err, lastValue?) => {

  if (err instanceof DisconnectedError) {

    // This error indicates that we've been disconnected,
    // resubscribing from the place we have stopped
    let continueQuery = {
      fromId: lastValue ? lastValue.id + 1 : startQuery.fromId,
      toId: startQuery.toId
    };

    return observeUnstable(continueQuery);

  } else {
    // Rethrowing error we don't expect
    throw err;
  }

}));
```

Here are my **ReconnectOperator** and **ReconnectSubscriber**:

```
class ReconnectOperator<T> implements Operator<T, T> {

  constructor(private handler: (err: any, lastValue?: T) => Observable<T>) {
  }

  call(subscriber: Subscriber<T>, source: any): any {
    return source.subscribe(new ReconnectSubscriber(subscriber, this.handler));
  }
}

class ReconnectSubscriber<T> extends Subscriber<T> {

  private lastValue?: T;

  constructor(destination: Subscriber<T>, private handler: (err: any, lastValue?: T) => Observable<T>) {
    super(destination);
  }

  protected _next(value: T) {
    this.lastValue = value;
    super._next(value);
  }

  error(err: any) {
    if (!this.isStopped) {
      let result: Observable<T>;
      try {
        result = this.handler(err, this.lastValue);
      } catch (err2) {
        super.error(err2);
        return;
      }

      // TODO: ???
      result.subscribe(this._unsubscribeAndRecycle());
      // this._unsubscribeAndRecycle();
      //this.source.subscribe(result);
      //this.add(subscribeToResult(this, result));
    }
  }
}
```

This subscriber is very similar to **CatchSubscriber** with only one difference is that CatchSubscriber returns original observable in selector method, in my case I want to return last value so the selector could use it to compose a brand new observable rather than reusing the original one.

But I messed with resubscribe logic somehow so the resulting observable never returns complete for small amount of test values, and crashes with stack overflow for bigger amount of test values.

Also, my idea here is to implement a new operator but if it's possible to implement it in a single method just using composition of existing operators, in a generic way, that would be even better :)

Example of an alternative method but without operator:

```
function observeStable<T, Q>(
    query: Q,
    continueQueryFunc: (query: Q, lastValue?: T) => Observable<T>
): Observable<T> {

  return observeUnstable<T>(query).catch((err, ???) =>
    if (err instanceof DisconnectedError) {
      let lastValue = ???
      let continueQuery = continueQueryFunc(query, lastValue);
      return observeUnstable(continueQuery);
    } else {
      throw err;
    }
  );
}
```